# How to fix "Type 'AttributeRouting.Framework.AttributeRoutingException' in assembly 'AttributeRouting, ...' is not marked as serializable." error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title but I'm not (obviously) serializing any objects that reference AttributeRouting, let alone the `AttributeRoutingException` type.

In Visual Studio the error info indicates that the relevant file is "ASPNETCOMPILER" – that's pretty unhelpful.

Superficially, this seems like it should be covered by one of these existing questions and their answers:

- [c# - Error - is not marked as serializable - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707872/error-is-not-marked-as-serializable)
- [c# - SerializationException Type "is not marked as serializable" - But it is - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507819/serializationexception-type-is-not-marked-as-serializable-but-it-is)
- [c# - Type in assembly is not marked as serializable - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307365/type-in-assembly-is-not-marked-as-serializable)

Comment: What type of project are you running? If you are running Mvc project then add routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes() method in your route config file. If you are running Web API 2 project then add config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() method in your web api config file to enable attribute routing.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee It's an MVC project but it's also an old project and routing has been working for *years*. I observed this error after adding the line I mention in my answer.

Comment: MVC 5 or VS 2015 enables you to use attribute routing. The route constraint parameter must correspond to the parameter of the ActionResult method. [Route("~/SomeRoute/id:string", Name = "SomeRoute")] 
public ActionResult SomeMethod(string id)
{

}

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Whoosh! You're missing some key information – attribute routing is already working. This is also an ASP.NET MVC *3* project and it's using the [AttributeRouting](http://mccalltd.github.io/AttributeRouting/#introduction) library because attribute routing wasn't yet part of ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/ Please have a look at this article.

Answer (score 0):

By process of elimination I determined that this line was the culprit:

```
[DELETE("entities/{id:Guid}")]
```

The line is an attribute on an ASP.NET MVC controller action method. The problem is the ['routing constraint'](http://mccalltd.github.io/AttributeRouting/#route-constraints) that indicates that `id` should be a GUID. The line should be like this instead:

```
[DELETE("entities/{id:guid}")]
```

[The only difference is that `guid` is all lowercase.]