# Serializable labeled class but not working

Tags: c#, serialization, priority-queue, c5

I recently wrote a code for copying a class with C5 library "IntervalHeap" but encountered an error message like this.

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Type
>   'C5.IntervalHeap`1+Interval[[TransSys1.Node, TransSys1,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' in Assembly
>   'C5, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=282361b99ded7e8e' is not marked as serializable.'

I checked the source code in [here](https://github.com/sestoft/C5) but the IntervalHeap class is already labeled as `[Serializable]`. I built the source code again but it still not working. I debugged my project with x64 platforms.

Can you let me know what are the potential reasons or how to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SerializationException Type "is not marked as serializable" - But it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507819/serializationexception-type-is-not-marked-as-serializable-but-it-is)

Comment: @orhtej2, It doesn't seem to be a duplicate to that question: that question related to `partial class` and `Form`, this assembly and type is neither of those https://github.com/sestoft/C5/blob/master/C5/heaps/IntervalHeap.cs the answer may be of consideration, but not apparent enough to relate it as a duplicate.

Comment: Thomas, gives us a code sample of the class you wrote that 'copies' (which I presume you mean inherits) this `IntervalHeap<T>` class.

Comment: more importantly, thomas, what are you passing as the generic `T`? if it is a class, is it marked as `serializable`?  can you try that real quick,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message points to the **`Interval`** struct, defined as inner struct within `C5.IntervalHeap<T>` 
noted as

```
C5.IntervalHeap`1+Interval
```

You get this error because this `Interval` struct is not marked `Serializable`.

Unless you own that source (maybe via a copy) there isn't much you can do about it.
Maybe find another way to take a copy, without serializing.

Comment: hmm.. you have enough rep to know the difference between a comment and answer, so why are you point at the exception as being the answer?

Comment: I read in OP's question: what are the potential reasons. Going to explain further what to do.

Comment: you're saying the potential reason for the exception is that a struct (a value type) should be marked as `serializable`?  you don't think perhaps it is the generic `T` referenced in the structure?

Comment: At this point it fails at the `Interval` struct as the error states: Type C5.IntervalHeap`1+Interval, which is the notation to an inner struct/class.